# How to mock objects in Kotlin?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, powermockito

I want to test a class that calls an object (static method call in java) but I'm not able to mock this object to avoid real method to be executed.

```
object Foo {
    fun bar() {
        //Calls third party sdk here
    }
}
```

I've tried different options like [Mockk](http://mockk.io/#object-mocks), [How to mock a Kotlin singleton object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977320/how-to-mock-a-kotlin-singleton-object) and using PowerMock in the same way as in java but with no success.

Code using PowerMockito:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(IntentGenerator::class)
class EditProfilePresenterTest {

    @Test
    fun shouldCallIntentGenerator() {

        val intent = mock(Intent::class.java)

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(IntentGenerator::class.java)
        PowerMockito.`when`(IntentGenerator.newIntent(any())).thenReturn(intent) //newIntent method param is context

       presenter.onGoToProfile()

       verify(view).startActivity(eq(intent))        

    }
}
```

With this code I get

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.sample.test.IntentGenerator$Companion.newIntent, parameter context

any() method is from [mockito_kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin). Then If I pass a mocked context to newIntent method, it seems real method is called.

Comment: How is it possible that you weren't successful with the the options you mentioned? Show us your code please!

Comment: Just a week ago I answered identical question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49126220/how-to-mock-kotlin-object-in-android/49126371#49126371

Comment: @Selvin Your comment didn't bring anything useful. Objects in Kotlin are totaly fine. I suggest reading about them first.

Comment: Code added @Lovis

Comment: Check your `any()`, it returns null.

Comment: what @ice1000 says.

Comment: And please tell us the signature of `newIntent`. If it's a `Context`, then replace `any()` with `any<Activity>()`.

Comment: or try `any<MockContext>()`

Comment: I've tried any<Activity>() and any<MockContext>() and same error is thrown, yes @ice1000 It's a context

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, that `object IntentGenerator` looks like a code smell, why would you make it an `object`? If it's not your code you could easily create a wrapper class

```
class IntentGeneratorWrapper {

    fun newIntent(context: Context) = IntentGenerator.newIntent(context)    

}
```

And use that one in your code, without static dependencies.

That being said, I have 2 solutions. Say you have an `object`

```
object IntentGenerator {
    fun newIntent(context: Context) = Intent()
}
```

**Solution 1 - Mockk**

With [Mockk](http://mockk.io) library the syntax is a bit funny compared to Mockito but, hey, it works:

```
testCompile "io.mockk:mockk:1.7.10"
testCompile "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0"
```

Then in your test you use `objectMockk` fun with your `object` as argument and that will return a scope on which you call `use`, within `use` body you can mock the `object`:

```
@Test
fun testWithMockk() {
    val intent: Intent = mock()
    whenever(intent.action).thenReturn("meow")

    objectMockk(IntentGenerator).use {
        every { IntentGenerator.newIntent(any()) } returns intent
        Assert.assertEquals("meow", IntentGenerator.newIntent(mock()).action)
    }
}
```

**Solution 2 - Mockito + reflection**

In your test resources folder create a `mockito-extensions` folder (e.g. if you're module is "app" -> `app/src/test/resources/mockito-extensions`) and in it a file named `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker`. In the file just write this one line `mock-maker-inline`. Now you can mock final classes and methods (both `IntentGenerator` class and `newIntent` method are final).

Then you need to

1. Create an instance of `IntentGenerator`. Mind that `IntentGenerator` is just a regular java class, I invite you to check it with `Kotlin bytecode` window in Android Studio
2. Create a spy object with Mockito on that instance and mock the method
3. Remove the final modifier from `INSTANCE` field. When you declare an `object` in Kotlin what is happening is that a class (`IntentGenerator` in this case) is created with a private constructor and a static `INSTANCE` method. That is, a singleton.
4. Replace `IntentGenerator.INSTANCE` value with your own mocked instance.

The full method would look like this:

```
@Test
fun testWithReflection() {
    val intent: Intent = mock()
    whenever(intent.action).thenReturn("meow")

    // instantiate IntentGenerator
    val constructor = IntentGenerator::class.java.declaredConstructors[0]
    constructor.isAccessible = true
    val intentGeneratorInstance = constructor.newInstance() as IntentGenerator

    // mock the the method
    val mockedInstance = spy(intentGeneratorInstance)
    doAnswer { intent }.`when`(mockedInstance).newIntent(any())

    // remove the final modifier from INSTANCE field
    val instanceField = IntentGenerator::class.java.getDeclaredField("INSTANCE")
    val modifiersField = Field::class.java.getDeclaredField("modifiers")
    modifiersField.isAccessible = true
    modifiersField.setInt(instanceField, instanceField.modifiers and Modifier.FINAL.inv())

    // set your own mocked IntentGenerator instance to the static INSTANCE field
    instanceField.isAccessible = true
    instanceField.set(null, mockedInstance)

    // and BAM, now IntentGenerator.newIntent() is mocked
    Assert.assertEquals("meow", IntentGenerator.newIntent(mock()).action)
}
```

The problem is that after you mocked the object, the mocked instance will stay there and other tests might be affected. A made a sample on how to confine the mocking into a scope [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49318722/1527232)

**Why PowerMock is not working**

You're getting

> Parameter specified as non-null is null

because `IntentGenerator` is not being mocked, therefore the method `newIntent` that is being called is the actual one and in Kotlin a method with non-null arguments will invoke `kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull` at the beginning of your method. You can check it with the bytecode viewer in Android Studio. If you changed your code to

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(IntentGenerator::class.java)
PowerMockito.doAnswer { intent }.`when`(IntentGenerator).newIntent(any())
```

You would get another error

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException:  Argument passed to
>   when() is not a mock!

If the object was mocked, the `newInstance` method called would not be the one from the actual class and therefore a `null` could be passed as argument even if in the signature it is non-nullable

Comment: Working with Mockk! Thanks!

Comment: @aloj you're welcome :) The second option was just for fun actually, I wouldn't use it in a commercial project

Comment: @lelloman you wrote that using `object IntentGenerator` is a code smell. Do you have any good sources on this subject? I am often struggle when to use `object` and when not to use it (apart from testability and stateful objects).

Comment: I would suggest uncle Bob's talks about clean code. My point there is not really against `object` itself, but the fact that you end up with a static dependency inside your class.

Answer (score -2):

[This blog post](https://antonioleiva.com/mockito-2-kotlin/) clearly demonstrates how to do this using mockito. I highly recommend this approach. It's really simple.

Basically, in your `src/test/resources` folder create a folder: `mockito-extensions`. Add a file in that directory called `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker`, and inside that file have the following text:

```
mock-maker-inline
```

You can now mock final kotlin classes and methods.

Comment: I already did that and can mock classes, problem is mocking objects

Comment: Oh. It works for Robolectric. I don't know how to mock objects. You'd have to create a mock instance of the object class, and then use reflection to swap out it's value on the `INSTANCE` variable where the object is stored.